# ¿Como codificar una matriz de prioridad?

Tags: java, codificación

Tengo realizar una calculadora, pero necesito saber como codificar la matriz de prioridad, para que por ejemplo realice primero la multiplicación y luego la suma.

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Las preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo. Lee [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) en el centro de ayuda para más información.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static int matriz(String s){
    int r = 0;
    switch(s){
        case "+":
        case "-":
            r = 1;
            break;
        case "*":
        case "/":
            r = 2;
            break;
    }
    return r;

}
```

También de esta forma lo podrías hacer ya que solo quieres saber si es mayo la importancia o no

Answer (score 2):

Tienes dos formas de hacer una matriz de prioridad, una es usando un Hashmap dentro de otro Hashmap

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> doubleKeyMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Object>>();

    // Agregar valores

    doubleKeyMap.put("key1A", new HashMap<String, Object>(){{put("key2A", "Test");}});
    doubleKeyMap.put("key1B", new HashMap<String, Object>(){{put("key2B", 123);}});
    doubleKeyMap.put("key1C", new HashMap<String, Object>(){{put("key2C", false);}});

    // Leer valores

    doubleKeyMap.get("key1A").get("key2A"); // Test (String)
    doubleKeyMap.get("key1B").get("key2B"); // 123 (int)
    doubleKeyMap.get("key1C").get("key1C"); // false (boolean)
    doubleKeyMap.get("key1A").get("key2B"); // null (No existe la combinación de keys)
```

o puedes crear un Hashmap en donde puedas ingresas el signo que ingresas primero y el contenido un metodo donde se relacione el resto de signos

```
public class MatrizPrioridad {

    public static int matriz() {
        /*
         * ArrayList<Contenido> matriz = new ArrayList<Contenido>(); Contenido cont;
         */

        // HashMap<Entry<Character, Character>, Integer> matriz = new
        // HashMap<Entry<Character,Character>, Integer>();

        /*
         * Pair<Character, Character> suma_resta = new Pair<Character, Character>('+',
         * '-'); Pair
         * 
         * matriz.put(suma, 1); matriz.put(suma_resta, 0);
         */
        // matriz.add(cont);

        // Map<new Map<Character, Character>, Integer> matriz = new Map<new
        // Map<Character, Character>, Integer>;
        HashMap<HashMap<Character, Character>, Integer> matriz = new HashMap<HashMap<Character, Character>, Integer>();
        ;

        matriz.put(new HashMap<Character, Character>() {
            {
                put('+', '+');
            }
        }, 1);
        // prueba

        return matriz.get('+');
    }

    public static Integer matrizSuma(Character obten) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> suma = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        suma.put('+', 1);
        suma.put('-', 1);
        suma.put('*', 0);
        suma.put('/', 0);
        suma.put('^', 0);

        Integer resultado = null;

        resultado = suma.get(obten);

        return resultado;
    }

    public static Integer matrizResta(Character obten) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> resta = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        resta.put('+', 1);
        resta.put('-', 1);
        resta.put('*', 0);
        resta.put('/', 0);
        resta.put('^', 0);

        Integer resultado = null;

        resultado = resta.get(obten);

        return resultado;
    }

    public static Integer matrizMultiplica(Character obten) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> multiplica = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        multiplica.put('+', 1);
        multiplica.put('-', 1);
        multiplica.put('*', 1);
        multiplica.put('/', 1);
        multiplica.put('^', 0);

        Integer resultado = null;

        resultado = multiplica.get(obten);

        return resultado;
    }

    public static Integer matrizDivide(Character obten) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> deivide = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        deivide.put('+', 1);
        deivide.put('-', 1);
        deivide.put('*', 1);
        deivide.put('/', 1);
        deivide.put('^', 0);

        Integer resultado = null;

        resultado = deivide.get(obten);

        return resultado;
    }

    public static Integer matrizPotencia(Character obten) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> potencia = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        potencia.put('+', 1);
        potencia.put('-', 1);
        potencia.put('*', 1);
        potencia.put('/', 1);
        potencia.put('^', 1);

        Integer resultado = potencia.get(obten);

        return resultado;
    }

    /*
     * public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println(matrizSuma('/'));
     * System.out.println(matrizResta('-'));
     * System.out.println(matrizMultiplica('+'));
     * System.out.println(matrizDivide('+'));
     * 
     * }
     */

    public Integer matrizPrincipal(Character signo, Character obten) {
        // HashMap<Character, Integer> matriz = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        Integer respuesta = null;
        if (signo.equals('+')) {
            respuesta = matrizSuma(obten);
            // EncontrarComando.addOp(new Suma());
            // System.out.println(matrizSuma(obten));
        } else {
            if (signo.equals('-')) {
                respuesta = matrizResta(obten);
                // EncontrarComando.addOp(new Resta());
            } else {
                if (signo.equals('*')) {
                    respuesta = matrizMultiplica(obten);
                    // EncontrarComando.addOp(new Multiplica());
                } else {
                    if (signo.equals('/')) {
                        respuesta = matrizDivide(obten);
                        // EncontrarComando.addOp(new Divide());
                    } else {
                        if (signo.equals('^')) {
                            respuesta = matrizPotencia(obten);
                        } else {
                            if (signo.equals('p')) {
                                respuesta = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /*
         * if(respuesta == 1) { ActivarComando.activar(obten); }else {
         * ActivarComando.activar(signo); }
         */

        return respuesta;
        // return matriz.get(obten);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Según el problema que planteas intenta hacer una matriz por cada operador de la siguiente manera:

```
public static Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, Integer>> matriz;

public static Hashtable<String, Integer> suma = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
public static Hashtable<String, Integer> resta = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
public static Hashtable<String, Integer> multiplacion = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
public static Hashtable<String, Integer> division = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();

public static void llenarMatrizDePrioridad() {
    if (matriz == null)
        matriz = new Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, Integer>>();

    suma.put("+", 1);
    suma.put("-", 1);
    suma.put("*", 0);
    suma.put("/", 0);

    resta.put("+", 1);
    resta.put("-", 1);
    resta.put("*", 0);
    resta.put("/", 0);

    multiplacion.put("+", 1);       
    multiplacion.put("-", 1);
    multiplacion.put("*", 1);
    multiplacion.put("/", 1);

    division.put("+", 1);
    division.put("-", 1);
    division.put("*", 1);
    division.put("/", 1);

    matriz.put("+", suma);
    matriz.put("-", resta);
    matriz.put("*", multiplacion);
    matriz.put("/", division);
}
```

Espero esto te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Tu respuesta fue reportada como duplicada, esto es la misma respuesta de otra pregunta : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99071/como-implementar-una-matriz-de-precedencia-de-operadores-aritméticos/99072#99072 te sugiero revisar [answer].