# ¿Como implementar una matriz de precedencia de operadores aritméticos?

Tags: java

He estado trabajando en la elaboración de una calculadora para un proyecto. Desafortunadamente he tenido algunos inconvenientes con la matriz de precedencia de los operadores Aritméticos porque no he logrado implementarlos dentro del código. Tengo una clase en donde he creado la matriz que contiene las diferentes operaciones y la logia da a entender que si, por ejemplo, tengo una multiplicación y una suma, el valor que retornará será 1, pero si tengo una suma y una multiplicación, este retornará 0. En el momento de la ejecución, el programa arroja NULL. ¿Cuál sería la manera más óptima para solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el problema que planteas intenta hacer una matriz por cada operador de la siguiente manera:

```
public static Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, Integer>> matriz;

public static Hashtable<String, Integer> suma = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
public static Hashtable<String, Integer> resta = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
public static Hashtable<String, Integer> multiplacion = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
public static Hashtable<String, Integer> division = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();

public static void llenarMatrizDePrioridad() {
    if (matriz == null)
        matriz = new Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, Integer>>();

    suma.put("+", 1);
    suma.put("-", 1);
    suma.put("*", 0);
    suma.put("/", 0);

    resta.put("+", 1);
    resta.put("-", 1);
    resta.put("*", 0);
    resta.put("/", 0);

    multiplacion.put("+", 1);       
    multiplacion.put("-", 1);
    multiplacion.put("*", 1);
    multiplacion.put("/", 1);

    division.put("+", 1);
    division.put("-", 1);
    division.put("*", 1);
    division.put("/", 1);

    matriz.put("+", suma);
    matriz.put("-", resta);
    matriz.put("*", multiplacion);
    matriz.put("/", division);
}
```

Espero esto te sea de ayuda.